# Beanstream Credit card payment integration in PHP

Tags: payment-gateway, beanstream

I am not able to Integrate Beanstream to my wbe page.

I am trying to submit the form which includes amount, Mer id, card details, action = https://www.beanstream.com/scripts/process_transaction.asp. 
It will goes to the beanstream page and doesn't come back.

The page which browser stops here : https://www.beanstream.com/scripts/process_transaction.asp?rbCCType=Visa&trnCardNum............

Can anybody please suggest how to proceed this. I tried from last couple of days, but not succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to submit a credit card purchase transaction, here is an example

```
<form action="https://www.beanstream.com/scripts/process_transaction.asp" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="merchant_id" value="YOUR-MERCHANT-ID" />
    <input type="text" name="trnAmount" value="5.00" />
    <input type="text" name="paymentMethod" value="CC" />
    <input type="text" name="trnCardOwner" value="John Doe" />
    <input type="text" name="trnCardType" value="VI" />
    <input type="text" name="trnCardNumber" value="4030000010001234" />
    <input type="text" name="trnExpMonth" value="01" />
    <input type="text" name="trnExpYear" value="17" />
    <input type="text" name="trnCardCvd" value="123" />

    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit Payment">
```

I have included a test card number, so just update merchant_id and try it. Or you could post to your code behind script which posts these fields to Beanstream. For more information see http://developer.beanstream.com/documentation/classic-apis/ and http://support.beanstream.com/